# Docker Security Scanning: How to integrate Clair with a docker private registry?

Tags: security, clair, registry

According to the following documentation it should be possible to integrate [clair](https://coreos.com/clair/docs/latest/) with a docker private registry. How to do that?

> **[Registry Integration](https://github.com/coreos/clair/blob/master/Documentation/running-clair.md#registry-integration)**
>
> Clair can be integrated directly into a container registry such that
>   the registry is responsible for interacting with Clair on behalf of
>   the user. This type of setup avoids the manual scanning of images and
>   creates a sensible location to which Clair's vulnerability
>   notifications can be propagated. The registry can also be used for
>   authorization to avoid sharing vulnerability information about images
>   to which one might not have access.

Comment: You may consider this image on docker hub for starting/playing with Clair: https://hub.docker.com/r/arminc/clair-local-scan/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both Docker Registry and Docker Engine have API interfaces.
I consider it should be possible to implement a Docker plugin for this integration to have images scanned for example as somebody pushes them. (side note - Docker registry is an image registry, not container registry).

This scanner functionality is also possible through the commercial Docker Enterprise edition.
https://docs.docker.com/docker-cloud/builds/image-scan/

UPD here an example with clair/docker, looks quite simple
http://blog.xebia.com/docker-containers-vulnerability-scan-clair/

Comment: [`could not find layer`](https://github.com/arminc/clair-scanner/issues/13)